# Getting clientId = null from OAuth2Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm new in Spring Security, so I have config for Resource Server like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServerSecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/public/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/public/**")
            .fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
    }
    
    @Bean
    RestAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler(){
        return new RestAccessDeniedHandler();
    }
    
    @Bean
    RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint(){
        return new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }
}
```

And I tried to get clientId from Keycloak AuthenticationService

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/token", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('survey')")
    public @ResponseBody ChameleonRestDataDto<ResponseSurveyTokenDto> getSurveyToken(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt token,
            @RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorization){
        try {
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            String clientId = ((OAuth2Authentication) authentication).getOAuth2Request().getClientId();
            
            return restDataDtoUtil.generateResponse(ChameleonRestStatusDto.Status.SUCCESS, "", null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
             ChameleonLogWriter.logError(this.getClass(), "getListBackground", "", e);
             String errorMessage = e.getClass() == ChameleonException.class ? e.getMessage()
                     : "Failed to get token.";

             return restDataDtoUtil.generateResponse(ChameleonRestStatusDto.Status.ERROR, errorMessage, null);
        }
    }
```

This is my spring version
[image]
`@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt token` always null. There's a missing configuration ?

After I tried for another spring version 2.5.4 with spring security 5.5.2, everything was fine.

Comment: It appears you are using the deprecated `spring-security-oauth` project. Please use the [OAuth 2.0 support provided by Spring Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide) instead.

Comment: I need old version, because my spring-boot-parent is 1.5.10-RELEASE. Can I use better way to get clientId from JWT instead of java Base64Decode ??